# Read text and return lists of different parts of speech

Tags: python, python-3.x

This function reads through text and returns lists of all the different parts of speech (nouns, verbs, proper nouns, etc.). My sense is that there is a more elegant and probably more efficient way to accomplish the same thing. The code feels really repetitive so I'm hoping there is a better way.

```
import nltk


def find_pos(tokens):

    '''This function accepts tokens as an input and returns a list of all
    the parts of speech.
    Note that some words are return twice:
    -Nouns are separated into common and proper as well as grouped together
    -Modals are added to verbs are well as returned separately'''

    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)

    # Now we devide them into groups
    # Note that IN can be either a preposition or a conjunction, for now we're going to list it with the prepositions
    common_noun_pos = ['NN', 'NNS']
    common_nouns = []
    verb_pos = ['VB', 'VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ']
    verbs = []
    adjective_pos = ['JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS']
    adjectives = []
    pronoun_pos = ['PRP', 'PRP$', 'WP', 'WP$']
    pronouns = []
    adverb_pos = ['RB', 'RBR', 'RBS', 'WRB']
    adverbs = []
    proper_noun_pos = ['NNP', 'NNPS']
    proper_nouns = []
    conjunction_pos = ['CC']
    conjunctions = []
    preposition_pos = ['IN', 'TO']
    prepositions = []
    interjection_pos = ['UH']
    interjections = []
    modal_pos = ['MD']  # But these are also verbs, include them
    modals = []
    tagged_other_pos = ['CD', 'DT', 'EX', 'FW', 'LS', 'PDT', 'POS', 'RP', 'SYM', 'WDT']
    tagged_others = []
    other = []

    for idx, token in enumerate(tagged):
        if token[1] in common_noun_pos:
            common_nouns.append(token)
        elif token[1] in verb_pos:
            verbs.append(token)
        elif token[1] in adjective_pos:
            adjectives.append(token)
        elif token[1] in pronoun_pos:
            pronouns.append(token)
        elif token[1] in adverb_pos:
            adverbs.append(token)
        elif token[1] in proper_noun_pos:
            proper_nouns.append(token)
        elif token[1] in conjunction_pos:
            conjunctions.append(token)
        elif token[1] in preposition_pos:
            prepositions.append(token)
        elif token[1] in interjection_pos:
            interjections.append(token)
        elif token[1] in modal_pos:
            modals.append(token)
        elif token[1] in tagged_other_pos:
            tagged_others.append(token)
        else:
            other.append(token)

    verbs.append(modals)
    nouns = common_nouns + proper_nouns
    parts_of_speech = [nouns, common_nouns, verbs, adjectives, pronouns, adverbs, proper_nouns, conjunctions,
                       prepositions, interjections, modals]
    return parts_of_speech
```

Here some code to test it:

```
text = 'It is a truth universally acknowledged, that a single man in possession of a good fortune, must be in ' \
       'want of a wife. However little known the feelings or views of such a man may be on his first entering a ' \
       'neighbourhood, this truth is so well fixed in the minds of the surrounding families, that he is ' \
       'considered the rightful property of some one or other of their daughters. '
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
find_pos(tokens)
```

Answer (score 1):

For some more typing up front, you can make the parsing slightly easier.

This uses the fact that two variables can point to the same (even mutable) object:

```
def find_pos(tokens):
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    # Define all lists (just like before), here with tuple unpacking:
    common_nouns, verbs, adjectives, pronouns, adverbs, proper_nouns, conjunctions, prepositions, interjections, modals, tagged_others, other = [
        [] for _ in range(12)]

    # Define a dictionary mapping from the positions to the lists:
    d = {'NN': common_nouns, 'NNS': common_nouns,
         'VB': verbs, 'VBD': verbs, 'VBG': verbs, 'VBN': verbs, 'VBP': verbs, 'VBZ': verbs,
         ...}

    # Use it like this:
    for token in tagged:
        d[token[1]].append(token)
    ...
```

---

Alternatively, do the calculations afterwards:

```
from collections import defaultdict


def find_pos(tokens):
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)

    d = defaultdict(list)
    for token in tagged:
        d[token[1]].append(token)

    def t(*pos):
        return sum([d[x] for x in pos], [])

    return [t('NN', 'NNS', 'NNP', 'NNPS'),
            t('NN', 'NNS'),
            t('VB', 'VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ'),
            ...]
```